# Adding object properties to a Java web service: do old WCF clients need to update service references?

Tags: c#, java, wcf, web-services, wsdl

We consume a Java Web Service and have compiled our solution against v1 of said service. We deploy. The Java service team adds a property to a return object (modifying WSDL) (towards the top of the soap message / data contract - [order is important in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272478/adding-field-to-wcf-data-contract-breaks-clients)?) and deploys v2 of said service. What happens to our client? Right now it seems we get default data (int = 0, bool = false etc.) after the new property that was added.

This is slightly different to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142813/adding-methods-to-the-webservice-do-old-clients-need-to-update-web-references) because the method signature remains the same but the return object changes.