# Need to split a column into two

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, wcf

I have a WCF service.

I have a field (say Name) and now client wants to change this into FirstName (first half before a space) and LastName (everything after a space).

This WCF service is being used by different applications and I want to accomplish this without breaking any existing clients.

Can I add two new datamember even though they are not exists in the database? How the value will be set or get for these two new datamembers?

Thanks

Comment: Bear in mind this is a pretty hard thing to do correctly.  What if someone has a space in their last name like `Mark Van Duser` or goes by initials `E.  F. Codd`?

Comment: Yup, or what if you have someone who only has one name, like quite a few footballers from africa... You might want to check if there is a space before trying to split by it, and then think about if you want it in FirstName or SecondName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the new data members are strings then this should be fine, the additional data members will be ignored by older versions of the service client.

See this related question:
[Adding field to WCF data contract breaks clients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272478/adding-field-to-wcf-data-contract-breaks-clients)

Comment: Adding the column should be fine, but how about the retrieving the data. I have the following datamember [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }. How will I add the two new datamember now?

Comment: Add them as [DataMember] public string FirstName { get; set; }, [DataMember] public string Surname { get; set; } (or similar) and then update your data access layer to populate accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work:

```
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(255)
SET @FullName = 'James Johnson'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@FullName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @FullName) - 1) AS FirstName,
       SUBSTRING(@FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', @FullName) + 1, LEN(@FullName)) AS LastName
```

The output from the above looks like this:

```
FirstName    LastName
------------ ----------------
John         Doe
```

To parse the name in code, the code example below should work fine for first and last names. If you need a robust parser that can handle prefixes, suffixes, and middle names take a look at [this article](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/splitting-a-name-into-first-and-last-names).

```
var names = ("James Johnson").Split(Convert.ToChar(" "));
if (names.Length > 0)  
    Response.Write(string.Format("First: {0}, Last: {1}", names[0], names[1]));
```

Comment: I want to perform this on the middle tier