# How to change the display order of properties within an object passed to a method (WCF)

Tags: c#, wcf, testing, wcftestclient

I have a couple of service methods that take an object as a parameter. In the WCF Test Client, the object's properties are displayed in alphabetical order. It would be expedient if we could list certain properties together. Is there a way to do this with an attribute or such like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `DataMember` attribute with `Order` parameter as:

```
[DataContract]
public class SomeAddress
{
   [DataMember(Order=0)]
   public string FirstName;

   [DataMember(Order=1)]
   public string LastName;
}
```

The original answer and more detail can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4274274/3021830).